# Connect dots on a grid with one continuous line

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, geometry

**Rules:**

1. Line must be **straight**.
2. Line must be **continuous**.
3. Line must **not intersect itself**.
4. Line is allowed to take **45 degree** turns to itself, for example:

[image: angle rule]

**The dots:**

[image: dots]

Comment: Does it matter how wide the line is?

Comment: @Stomf - the line's width is intended to be not bigger than the width of a dot and not so narrow that it is not visible. But since rules do not prohibit the grid-wide line anything goes :D Not going to change the rules after the puzzle has been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not written that the lines can or cannot leave the square...

What about this?

> [image]

Comment: That is one of the correct solutions, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Now that the devil is out of the box, let's see what is the minimum of lines that can cover all dots.

The minimum I can do is

> 13 lines.

And here is how it can be done.

But before looking at the solution, have a try!

> [image]

Comment: Very interesting, may I ask what did you use to find the minimum of lines?

Comment: Pencil and paper.  ... and eraser.