# Connect dots on a grid with one continuous line 2.0

Tags: visual, geometry

This is the same question posted by [webadventurer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/85112/web-adventurer) with one extra condition (number 5) that disallows the previous solution posted [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122177/connect-dots-on-a-grid-with-one-continuous-line/122179#122179).

(All credits go to webadventurer, including all images.)

**Rules:**

1. Line must be **straight**.
2. Line must be **continuous**.
3. Line must **not intersect itself**.
4. Line is allowed to take **45 degree** turns to itself, for example:

[image: angle rule]

**5. Line must not leave the square**.

**The dots:**

[image: dots]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I mean, as long as the number of segments doesn't matter..

> [image]

Comment: And they call it .... "[thinking outside the box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box)" !!!

Answer (score 9):

This might be the intended answer.  Only slightly out of the box.

> [image]

Then of course, people want to know what is the minmum.

OK, I tried.  I managed to go down to ...

> 21 lines instead of 25.
>
>  [image]
>
>  But somehow the apparent waste at the ends is not very satisfactory.

Comment: Also a good answer! I decided to award Bass the tick as they have posted the answer first, though your answer is quite elegant.

Comment: No problem.  Actually his answer inspired mine.

Comment: @CatProgrammer: The next question is... what is the minimum number of bends?

Comment: Surely "inside the square" still gives you some margin to go a little bit past the centres of the outer dots?

Comment: Maybe, but I am a bit purist.  Taking the square of dots as the limit makes more sense.  The frame around it is of an unspecified and arbitrary size.