# Connect dots on a grid with one continuous line (optimization)

Tags: mathematics, visual, geometry

(This question is the third puzzle of the Connect dots puzzle series. You can find the first two puzzles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122177/connect-dots-on-a-grid-with-one-continuous-line) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122181/connect-dots-on-a-grid-with-one-continuous-line-2-0), respectively.
The original question and photos originate from [webadventurer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/85112/web-adventurer). This optimization question was first asked by [user21820](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11806/user21820).)

---

**Rules:**

1. Line must be **straight**.
2. Line must be **continuous**.
3. Line must **not intersect itself**.
4. Line is allowed to take **45 degree** turns to itself, for example:

[image: angle rule]

**The dots:**

[image: dots]

---

Question: what is the minimum number of bends required to connect all the dots with one line?
In addition, how would this number change if we include the fifth rule:
**5. Line must not leave the square.**

(Bonus question: Is it possible to prove the lower bound? Is there an equation for the lower bound given $n \times n$ dots on a grid?)

---

Without rule 5, the record currently belongs to [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136/florian-f) with 12 bends (13 lines), whose solution can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122208/85635).

With rule 5, the record also currently belongs to [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136/florian-f) with 24 bends (25 lines), whose solution can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122201/85635).

Comment: Do you mean 135?

Comment: In the linked answer, Florian F has found a solution to the bonus with 20 bends (21 lines).